# Expected import directive or contract definition... going crazy. same code different result

Tags: contract-development

i am learning from a video course but the teacher doesnt have got the error i got.

so we have the same code but different result (error on mine and all ok on his)

here my code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

interface Regulator {
    function checkValue(uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function loan() external returns (bool);
}

contract Bank is Regulator {
    uint private value;
    address private owner;

    modifier ownerFunc {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    constructor(uint amount) public {
        value = amount;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function deposit(uint amount) public ownerFunc {
        value += amount;
    }

    function withdraw(uint amount) public ownerFunc {
        if (checkValue(amount)) {
            value -= amount;
        }
    }

    function balance() public view returns (uint) {
        return value;
    }

    function checkValue(uint amount) public returns (bool) {
        // Classic mistake in the tutorial value should be above the amount
        return value >= amount;
    }

    function loan() public returns (bool) {
        return value > 0;
    }
}

contract MyFirstContract is Bank(10) {
    string private name;
    uint private age;

    function setName(string newName) public {
        name = newName;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string) {
        return name;
    }

    function setAge(uint newAge) public {
        age = newAge;
    }

    function getAge() public view returns (uint) {
        return age;
    }
}

contract TestThrows {
    function testAssert() public pure {
        assert(1 == 2);
    }

    function testRequire() public pure {
        require(2 == 1);
    }

    function testRevert() public pure {
        revert();
    }

    function testThrow() public pure {
        throw;
    }
}
```

the error is on:

```
 interface Regulator {
    function checkValue(uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function loan() external returns (bool);
}
```

thanks a lot guys.
Have a nice time.

Comment: Can you provide more details, e.g., the Error you got, the link to the video etc...
Moreover, I don't know if this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

Change line 1:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;
```

Change line 81:

```
revert();
```

**Explanation**

The idea of `pragma ^` just sort of assumes that v4 or better will suffice. But there are breaking changes, deprecated words and so on. A more precise explanation isn' possible because we don't know what compiler version you're using and targeting.

I usually recommend the habit of specifying a precise version to avoid this kind head-scratcher. I have seen contracts that mix up different dialects. It's better, obviously, to get a clean compile on something.

You can, for example, change to `0.5.2` and then you will get a complaint about specifying `memory` or `storage`, so the compiler is trying to help you sort version differences.

You would rewrite these two lines:

```
function setName(string memory newName) public {
function getName() public view returns (string memory) {
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the difference is because of different compiler versions in use.

The first line is just a hint/suggestion/restriction and it doesn't actually define the used compiler. The actually used compiler is the actual compiler used. For example in Remix the compiler version can be chosen from a dropdown.

Especially if you are using some of the early 0.4.x versions there was for example no keyword `constructor`. This came only around 0.4.25 or somewhere there. So you would get plenty of errors with your code if your compiler is too old.

I suggest you use a new compiler and change the `pragma` to point to a new compiler as well.